# Freeze graph error while preparing custom tensorflow mobile model

Tags: tensorflow

I am preparing a custom model to run on android phone using instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models

First i retrained the model on custom images using below command:

```
$ python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --image_dir tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/my_images/ --learning_rate=0.0005 --testing_percentage=15 --validation_percentage=15 --train_batch_size=32 --validation_batch_size=-1  --flip_left_right True --random_scale=30 --random_brightness=30 --eval_step_interval=100 --how_many_training_steps=100 --tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/1
```

and as next step, I tested the model using `label_image.py` which also works fine in predicting the input image. However, freeze_graph gives error

`$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_graph.pb`

However, I keep getting this error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   57: invalid start byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that your `--input_graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb`. Is your graph written as binary file (`as_text=False`), instead of `pbtxt`? If so, you will need to pass the `--input_binary=true` flag to `freeze_graph`.

Answer (score 1):

if you write your graph as a binary file using:

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, 'tarinGraph', 'train2.pbtxt', as_text=False)
```

then you will need to pass the `--input_binary=true flag to freeze_graph`.